# Winapi Desktops. На каком рабочем столе работает смена пользователя в windows?

Tags: windows, winapi

В справке Winapi https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/winstation/desktops
написано, что по умолчанию в системе есть три рабочих стола Default, ScreenSaver и Winlogon.
Если я правильно понял описание, то:
Default - Это рабочий стол пользователя где работают программы пользователя.
Winlogon - "Защищённый" рабочий стол на котором отображаются запросы UAC, экран блокировки и экран входа пользователей в систему.
ScreenSaver - Рабочий стол для отображения защищённого скрин сейвера.
Я сделал два приложения:
1. Служба, которая запускается от имени LocalSystem.
2. Java приложение которое делает скриншоты рабочего стола.

Моя служба запускает моё java приложение, java приложение успешно делает скриншоты рабочих столов Winlogon и Default. На них я вижу запросы UAC, экран блокировки и окно входа пользователей в систему, то окно где нужно выбрать пользователя, который должен войти в систему.
Но... когда я хочу сменить пользователя в windows, я уже не могу получить скриншот рабочего стола Winlogon, точнее скриншот получается, но выглядит просто как чёрный квадрат. Такое ощущение, что окно смены пользователя работает на каком-то другом рабочем столе. 
Вопрос: Есть ли ещё какой-то рабочий стол о котором я не знаю, на котором может работать окно смены пользователя? Например программа удалённого доступа TeamViewer видит окно смены пользователя.